# .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 without Visual Studio installed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I found many topics regarding this issue but it looks like it none of them can help me. I'm trying to install DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe without Visual Studio installed - basically it's our build machine. When I run executable I get: **"This product requires Visual Studio 2015 ..."** . I've already tried to use **SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1** and it didn't help.

Context:
We have TeamCity server build agents hosted on different machine and we don't want to install Visual Studio there. One of our project is *.xproj project and it cannot be built due to the following error: `" error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.` 
What I found so far is that I should install Vs2015Tools in order to build it. I have already installed .NET core SDK.

Comment: Are you building using the dotnet CLI?  You can't simply use msbuild or you will run into this problem.  xproj is a deprecated format probably precisely because it is confusing like this.  It simply instructs VS2015 to use the dotnet CLI to build.  So what you should be doing is installing the .NET Core SDK (you said you did already?) and then go to the directory with the project.json file and run `dotnet build`

Comment: @borrrden I tried to do that. xproj has a dependency to csproj so when I run dotnet build on xproj it tries to build csproj and I get the following 
 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
It looks like something is messed up with dependencies. It works locally with VS2015 installed.

Comment: That's tougher to set up and I would recommend against trying to do that.  I've been down this road before and in the end I gave up and made the move to VS 2017 and the new csproj based .NET core format.  It's way easier, but I can understand not being able to switch.  It might make things easier if you explain the setup in the question though (for example, what does your project.json look like and what dependencies does the dependent csproj have, and what framework is it targeting etc)

Comment: @borrrden thank you for the answer. I went for VS2015 installation on dev server and it works perfectly now. When we are able to migrate to vs2017 we will definitely do that and try do avoid vs installation